# class not found even it's included PHP

Tags: php, response

[image]

the path also correct but i still don't know why it shows class not found as a fatal error

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('../core/Http/Response.php');

use core\Http;

 if(class_exists("Response")){
  echo "ok";
}
else {
  echo "doesn't exist";
 }
  $r = new Response();
  $r->header('test');
?>
```

Comment: That's because there is no class called "Response", only "Core\Http\Response". Always a good idea to read [the docs for your function calls](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) before posting a question.

Comment: sorry but the class already exists

Comment: You're missing the point: if you want to run `if(class_exists("Response"))`, there is no `Response` class in scope, the only class you would be able to find is your namespaced `Core\Http\Response` class, so use the fully qualified name as argument to `class_exists()`.

Comment: i've just added \ before the class name and it worked, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

normal call in php file,

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('../core/Http/Response.php');

use Core\Http\Response;
if(class_exists( 'Core\Http\Response' )){
    $r = new Response(); // -OR- $r = new Core\Http\Response();
}else{
    die('class doesn\'t exist');
}

$r->header('test');
?>
```

If you want to call in any controller, call like following

```
<?php
// Start of the file
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('../core/Http/Response.php');
use Core\Http\Response;

// your class
class Test extends Test_Controller {

    public function test(){     
        if(class_exists( 'Core\Http\Response' )){
            $r = new Response(); // -OR- $r = new Core\Http\Response();
        }else{
            die('class doesn\'t exist');
        }
        $r->header('test');     
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: are you sure about the `../core/Http/Response.php` file location

Comment: i have tested without including the file, its worked, check it here : https://paiza.io/projects/bhrSiwQi5zxtSMAz7ev0Wg?language=php

i think, there's something wrong with the file... load the file like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/core/Http/Response.php`

Comment: i have tried all this, but still not working i really do not know what's the issue

Comment: @elma, check my updated answer. i hope now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/Core/Http/Response.php';
 
use \Core\Http\Response;

$test = new Response("test response"); 
echo $test ;
?>
```